# android - How do I detect if you lean the phone to the right and left?

Tags: java, android

Imagine yourself a steering wheel and yourself playing a racer game. That's kind of what I want to do. I need to detect if the user is leaning the phone (or steering the wheel) to the right or left, how do I detect that?

Comment: to be fair, there's extensive documentation over on [Android Developers](https://developer.android.com/guide/topics/sensors/index.html) This is very poor of OP in not doing further research for themselves. We are not here to dish out links to extensive documentation found elsewhere.

Comment: But you did just dish out a link tho

Comment: The resources are out there, just lazy to find the documentation yourself.

Comment: I did actually attempt to find it by using Google. This question at this site will help future googlers which have the same question, so they can easily find those docs. However, I did not force you to link me anything.

Comment: Problem is, the Help under Android Studio is **visibly there**, plus, the documentation comes with the SDK!

Comment: I don't have Android Studio

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Achieved by SensorEvent implement, This class represents a Sensor event and holds informations such as the sensor's type, the time-stamp, accuracy and of course the sensor's data.

Android Official data:[SensorEvent|Android Developers](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/hardware/SensorEvent.html)

Comment: Thanks for the help!